# How to change tomcat version in Tomcat maven plugin?

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, pom.xml, maven-tomcat-plugin

```
<plugin>
<groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
<artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<version>2.1</version>
```

By default this plugin gives Tomcat version 7.0.37, how can we point to Tomcat version 7.0.91?
As our security team came up with some vulnerabilities for 7.0.37, we need to upgrade to 7.0.91.
Is there any way we can configure the dependencies for the plugin?

Comment: I recommend a different approach.  The maven-tomcat-plugin is essentially a dead project (see https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MTOMCAT-234 ), so if you are using this as a way to implement an embedded Tomcat server, you would be better of using SpringBoot.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

there is a newer version of `tomcat7-maven-plugin` which uses the tomcat `7.0.47` version. Maybe you want to give it a try.

if you really want to update the version referenced by the plugin you can try to exclude the particular references in the plugin and add dependencies in the dependencies section for the ones you excluded.

```
<dependencies>
    ... 
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-util</artifactId>
         <version>7.0.91</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>

            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
                    <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.1</version>
                    <exclusions>
                        <exclusion>
                            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
                            <artifactId>tomcat-util</artifactId>
                        </exclusion>
                    </exclusions>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
    <plugins>
<build>
```

Answer (score 2):

Additional to the answer from aurelius and for documentation reasons:

It's also documented on the plugin page how to replace given tomcat dependencies with new ones:

https://tomcat.apache.org/maven-plugin-trunk/tomcat7-maven-plugin/adjust-embedded-tomcat-version.html